# An example of set which is complete but not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to find an example of set which is complete but not compact.

Comment: Sets don't have either the property of completeness or compactness. Compactness is a property of topological spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) and completeness is a property of metric spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) or, if you prefer, uniform spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of a complete metric space which is not compact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049266/example-of-a-complete-metric-space-which-is-not-compact). It was asked a year later, but it was better worded. No +7 answer, but basically the same counterexample.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbb{R}$ is complete but not compact.

In fact, a uniform space is compact iff it is complete and [pre-compact](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pre-compact_space). So in a finite dimensional normed space, every nonbounded closed subset works.

Answer (score -2):

take a unit circle in complex then apply the hyperbolic metric the set is complete but not compact
hyperbolic metric(ds2)=dx2+dy2/(1-x2-y2)2

Comment: Please add some more detail.