# Example of a complete metric space which is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there any example of a complete metric space which is not compact? Why?

Comment: Any infinite discrete metric space?

Comment: The real line with the usual distance.

Comment: @James: $(0,1)$ is not complete...

Comment: @Sal haha good point! There is some weirdness with $(0,1)$ and completeness but it is nearly 10 and I obviously can't remember precisely what it is.

Comment: @Sal Got it, $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ but the first is complete, while the second is not (with their standard metrics). However if you pull the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ through any homeomorphism, then the metric on $(0,1)$ induces the normal topology, yet is complete. So, completeness is really a notion to do with metric, not topology, which I recall being surprising.

Comment: @James: That's indeed true, $(0,1)$ becomes complete when given the metric from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Sal So $(0,1)$ is not compact under the metric topology generated by $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: @Sal For $d$ I meant $d(x,y) = |x - y|$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is complete in its standard metric, but not compact. The open cover
$$\mathbb{R}=\cdots\cup(-3,-1)\cup(-2,0)\cup (-1,1)\cup (0,2)\cup (1,3)\cup\cdots$$
has no finite subcover. For a different argument: the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ has no convergent subsequence (and for metric spaces, compact $\iff$ sequentially compact).

Comment: Ha! I clicked on this question in order to give my most succinct answer ever: "$\mathbb R$" But you beat me to it. ;-)

Comment: @Sal, easier, $\mathbb{R}$ is a subselt of it self that is not bounded...

Answer (score 2):

in a metric space you may define Cauchy sequences and convergent sequences in the usual way.

$\{a_i\}$ is Cauchy iff $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists N.m,n \gt N \Rightarrow d(a_m,a_n) \lt \epsilon $

$\{a_i\}$ converges to $a$ iff $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists N.m \gt N \Rightarrow d(a_m,a) \lt \epsilon$

(sequential) *compactness* requires that *every* sequence contains a convergent subsequence

*completeness* requires that every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

since compactness implies, in particular, that a Cauchy sequence contains a convergent subsequence, then (in the metric space context) a compact set must be complete. the reverse need not be the case - completeness is a statement about Cauchy sequences, whereas compactness is a statement about all sequences.

the standard counterexamples are unbounded sequences in complete spaces.

Comment: THX!But why a Cauchy sequence contains a convergent subsequence implies this Cauchy sequence is convergent?